# delete UITableViewCell,depend on what section it is in

Tags: ios, uitableview

I got a problem: I have a 2 sections UITableView,i want the cells in section one can be delete(when swipe left show the delete),and the cells in section two cannot be delete.

somebody give me a hint ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol to determine whether the row can be deleted or not...

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Then, to handle the delete you will use the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Check editing style and take action (delete or edit)
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"Delete row %ld in section %ld", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section);
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you have already implemented the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate protocol, so it should only be a matter of adding these methods.

Comment: thanks, it work. just forget the "- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" method. anyway, thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Would you mind accepting the answer if this is what you were looking for? :)